# Webservice Response without Soap Wrapper

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, asmx

Whenever you call any webservice in response it will include the response with the soap wrapper in it. Is there any way we can return webservice response without any soap wrapper.

e.g. This is what soap response looks like:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <getEmployeeListResponse xmlns="http://test.com/Employee/">
            <getEmployeeListResult>
                <EmployeeLookup>
                    <Employee>                  
                        <Id>123</Id>
                        <Name>John</Name>
                    </Employee>
                    <Employee>
                        <Id>325</Id>
                        <Name>Henry</Name>
                    </Employee>
                </EmployeeLookup>
            </getEmployeeListResult>
        </getEmployeeListResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And i want something like this:

```
<EmployeeLookup>
    <Employee>                  
        <Id>123</Id>
        <Name>John</Name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <Id>325</Id>
        <Name>Henry</Name>
    </Employee>
</EmployeeLookup>
```

Just wanted to know if it is possible through webservice or not?
Thanks

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If it doesn't return the SOAP "wrapper", then it's not returning SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the service response will always have the soap header, you have to extract the body from the response stream.